# why $E_1$ is infinite?

Tags: real-analysis

I have some  confusion in **Rudin book**

My doubt is given below  mark in red line and red box
[image]

**My attempt** :

[image]

$E_1=  x_{11}$

$E_2= x_{21} ,x_{12}$

$E_3= x_{31},x_{22} , x_{13}$

............so on

clearly i can see $E_1$ is finite since $E_1=  x_{11}$

But here i am getting confused the  statement that   $E_1$  is infinite  .

My doubt is that  why  $E_1$  is infinite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E_1$ is the first row of the table, so $E_1 = \{x_{11}, x_{12}, x_{13}, \dots \}$.

Comment: thanks u @gandalf61 okay i was thinking opposite   ,i thought that array represent  $E_n$ sequence